# rabbitmq messages missing in receiver part

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I have implemented RabbitMQ in my servers. So basically what it does is that the main server passes messages to the worker server.
The problem that I am facing is that all the message that I pass is not received by the server.
i.e if i send 10 messages only  4 of them are received.

Any idea where am I going wrong.

Receiving code

```
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] Received %r" % body)

channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue='hello',
                      no_ack=True)

print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
channel.start_consuming()
```

Publishing code

```
import pika
import sys

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='task_queue', durable=True)

message = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]) or "Hello World!"
channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='task_queue',
                      body=message,
                      properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                         delivery_mode = 2, # make message persistent
                      ))
print(" [x] Sent %r" % message)
connection.close()
```

Comment: are you sure no one else is listening to the same queue... most common of the problem that i have faced

Comment: @Abhishek i have 2 listners..am passing 10 elements..but they are receing only 2 each..and there are no other listners listenng to same queue

Comment: Can you provide your publishing code as well?

Comment: @DaniilFedotov now i have added publishing code also

Comment: Is that exact code you use? It's publishing and consuming from different queues.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are publishing to the same queue (as the examples you posted shows otherwise). I would recommend that you enable the [confirm delivery](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html) flag. This will ensure that your message gets delivered, and if not it will either throw an exception, or publish will return False.

```
channel = connection.channel()
channel.confirm_delivery()
published = channel.basic_publish(...)
if not published:
    raise Exception("Unable to publish message!")
```

It might also be worth to install the [management plugin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) for RabbitMQ and inspect the queue before you start consuming messages. This way you can verify that the messages got published, and later consumed.